# Why does my WebService client request the WSDL from the server when consuming the service?

Tags: web-services, redirect, wsdl, cxf

I have a WS client deployed in Websphere container under linux that successfully calls a WebService published by a different application (I used CXF implementation). When I try the same client in a Tomcat container under Windows it behaves differently: wireshark captures reveal:

1. before invoking the webservice call my client requests the WSDL from the server at URL A
2. the server redirects the client to a different URL B
3. the client gets the WSDL from URL B.
4. Since the WSDL has a reference to an XSD file, the client requests the XSD from URL B assuming that the redirection also applies to the XSD file
5. The server responds with a not found error and the communication fails

My questions are:

- A) How can it be that the client assumes that the XSD is at URL B, but it is actually at URL A?
- B) Why is it that the same client does not ask for the WSDL when running on Websphere under Linux and it does ask for it when running on Tomcat under Windows? Is there any way to prevent it from requesting the WSDL an thus avoid the redirection issue?

Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: Share some code. I guess it depends on the way you are invoking the web service.

Comment: If the cliend already knows the service structure, there's absolutely no reasont to call for the WSDL. When you say "client", you mean `.war` application, right? I agree with @DiogoSantana. It is hard to help without seeing some code (maybe where the call is made?).

Comment: @acdcjunior CXF supports [dynamic client](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/dynamic-clients.html), so it may be necessary to download the WSDL.